# Why is Spring-Cloud-GCP no longer part of the Spring Cloud release train?

Tags: spring-cloud-gcp

Why is Spring-Cloud-GCP no longer part of the Spring Cloud release train while the AWS one is?

Answer (score 2):

Neither is part of the Spring Cloud release train anymore. See: https://spring.io/blog/2019/07/24/simplifying-the-spring-cloud-release-train